# How to get specific value from Regex match grouping in C#

Tags: c#, regex, twitter

I'm working on getting the `screen_name` and `tweetid` from the Twitter urls based on the regular expression group matching.

```
(http(s)?:\/\/)(?:www.)?twitter\.com\/@?(#!\/)?(?<screenname>[a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,15})(?:\/status(?:es)?\/)?(?<tweetid>\d+)?
```

I was able to get the Twitter `screen_name` and `tweetid` on the following links:

- https://twitter.com/IMDb/status/1044665597026594817
- https://twitter.com/BeastsMovieUK?lang=en
- http://www.twitter.com/@BeastsMovieUK

However, I could not get the correct `screen_name` and `tweetid` on the following links:

- http://www.twitter.com/i/web/status/1044713346405023744
- https://twitter.com/intent/user?screen_name=tyrabanks

I tried some changes on the regular expression but failed to make it works on the above links.

This are the codes I used to process this the regular expression.

```
Regex test = new Regex(@"(http(s)?:\/\/)(?:www.)?twitter\.com\/@?(#!\/)?(?<screenname>[a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,15})(?:\/status(?:es)?\/)?(?<tweetid>\d+)?", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
var matches = test.Matches("https://twitter.com/BeastsMovieUK/status/1042682155590197248");
Match m = null;
if (matches.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (Match match in matches)
    {
        if (match.Groups["tweetid"].Success)
        {
            m = match;
            Console.WriteLine("tweetid: {0}", m);
            break;
        }

        if (match.Groups["screenname"].Success)
        {
            m = match;
            Console.WriteLine("screenname: {0}", m);
        }
    }
}
Console.WriteLine("tweetid result: {0}", m.Groups["tweetid"]);
Console.WriteLine("screenname result: {0}", m.Groups["screenname"]);
```

This is my working sample: https://dotnetfiddle.net/wPoCSY

Comment: Try [this regex](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=https%3f%3a%2f%2f%28%3f%3awww%5c.%29%3ftwitter%5c.com%2f%40%3f%28%3f%3a%23!%2f%7ci%2f%29%3f%28%3f%28%3f%3d.*intent%2fuser%5c%3fscreen_name%29.*intent%2fuser%5c%3fscreen_name%3d%28%3f%3cscreenname%3e%5cw%2b%29%7c%28%3f%3cscreenname%3e%5cw%7b1%2c15%7d%29%28%3f%3a%2fstatus%28%3f%3aes%29%3f%2f%29%3f%28%3f%3ctweetid%3e%5cd%2b%29%3f%29&i=http%3a%2f%2fwww.twitter.com%2fi%2fweb%2fstatus%2f1044713346405023744%0d%0ahttps%3a%2f%2ftwitter.com%2fintent%2fuser%3fscreen_name%3dtyrabanks), see [the C# demo](https://ideone.com/PfjSud)

Comment: The code should be adjusted as always.

Answer (score -1):

If your two URL's are always going to be in the same format you could always just use `Split` on them. Here's a working example:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/Dda0if